# Bootstrap(Laravel) assets 404-error from Docker(Nginx)

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

**The goal:**

*Make newly created Laravel6 projects' bootstrap assets layout work from Docker.*

**Symptoms:**
Bootstrap assets work properly on local Laravel development environment (XAMPP -**Apache**- +Win10Pro), both the js and css are loaded well. But does'not work properly from local Docker (Win10-linux containers, **Nginx**+PHP+MySql+Redis), app.js and app.css runs on error 404.

Apache(local xampp):

[image]

Nginx(Docker):

[image]

What I did:

- New Laravel project created, auth added, bootstrap, npm and node installed
  properly.
- Virtual Host settings (httpd-vhosts.conf) for **Apache** in xampp:
  [image]

  - nginx.conf in nginx container

[image]

- Virtual Host settings (default.conf) for **Nginx** in nginx container:
  [image]
- .htaccess file in my projectfolder /a_new_app_for_test/public/

[image]

- docker-compose.yml for nginx

[image]

- docker-compose.yml for app

[image]

**What settings should I add/change in order to make assets loaded correctly?**

I suppose it could be related to nginx settings compiled into Docker.

Any help are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy your whole project to the container volume, this way nginx will be able to see your files from public or resources folder.

```
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/
```